# Create upload folder in FlexForm

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Good afternoon. I have a flexform that loads images and it works fine. But she does not know how to create a folder for unloading herself. Is there an additional config for this in TYPO3

```
<settings.sideImages>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>Images</label>
        <config>
            <type>group</type>
            <internal_type>file</internal_type>
            <allowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,png</allowed>
            <uploadfolder>uploads/tx_MYPLUGIN/</uploadfolder>
            <maxitems>20</maxitems>
            <size>3</size>
            <show_thumbs>0</show_thumbs>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</settings.sideImages>
```

Answer (score 0):

For create upload folder in your custom TYPO3 extension. You need to add below configuration in `ext_emconf.php` like below.

```
$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array(
   'uploadfolder' => 'true',
)
```

After added this changes you need to once Install / Un-install extension.